# Compare two schema's in MySQL and detect compatibility

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, compatibility

My use case is to take data from one version of MySQL schema and put it in another. So even before putting the data, I want to check if the schema of the source is compatible with destination. For examples, if the new column is added in the destination and which is nullable, then they are still compatible, where as dropping a column is not compatible change since source now has extra column and destination doesn't and will break import of data.

Comment: This is not clear. What is your question? What have you tried? How are you stuck? Why *bother* to check first?

Comment: The question is to compare whether two schemas are compatible in the sense, whether data from one can be inserted into another without error. I have tried of options like string parsing but it's getting complicated. We want to throw error ahead since customer will not understand sql insertion errors

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments. PS This is too broad & you have shown no effort. Also there are many similar validation/migration questions already you can google with site:stackoverflow.com or site:dba.stackexchange.com. Please see [ask] & other [help] links and ask a specific question about being stuck in the context of research & work you have done.

Answer (score 1):

to compare the schema of two MySQL databases I suggest to use:

**TiCodeX SQL Schema Compare** (https://www.ticodex.com).

It also gives you the migration script to update the destination database in case there are differences.

It's a very cheap but professional tool and with the same license you can use it also for MicrosoftSQL and PostgreSQL databases.

It's worth to mention that is the only tool I've found that also works nicely on Linux and MacOS.

Comment: Ticodex is bancrupt. https://www.moneyhouse.ch/de/company/ticodex-sa-in-liquidazione-21108917591